# How to optimize scene loading in Unity3D

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, loading

I was wondering if there is any way to speed up level loading in unity3d. I currently have loading level between both scenes, but it yet takes around 5 sec to load new level on ipad3. That's quite a lot.

I've optimized all start and awake functions so there is realy little stuf going on there. However i have a lot of sprites in each scene and i think they took most of the loading time.

Could I somehow determine which objects needs to be load at start and which can load during first 10 secs of level? I tried adding level additive but that makes my game to lag for sec or two.

Any smart way of speeding it up?

Comment: The answer is "yes! you can somehow determine that." However, without knowing what your game logic is, it's impossible to say *how* you would determine it. Have you run the profiler to check what's taking the time? This is the first step in addressing any performance issue.

Comment: How are you loading the objects? I ask this because I too was experiencing scene loading issues and I'll share how I improved performance. I was attempting to load around 30,000 blocks which were in chunks of 32x32 lots. I was instantiating these chunks inside of a nested for loop. The for loop created a lot of lag because it was trying to instantiate another chunk before the previous chunk was loaded. This was taking around 10 seconds to load. I improved this by adding a delay with the WaitForSeconds method using a delay of 0.05 seconds. This had my scene loaded in around half the time :)

Comment: I'm not instantiating anything in code. I don't know how to run profiler to see what is taking long time to load. Once the scene is loaded it's almost instantly runing.

Comment: With the limited information you are giving it is really hard to help you... Maybe you should start instantiating the objects from a script? That way you can control when they are loaded...

Comment: @gabrjan Are you using Unity Pro or free? It matters for what I am about to suggest.

Comment: Either cut down the number of assets you load on startup or warm them up before loading the next scene/level (DontDestroyOnLoad). Might use lowpolies as well (or most distant LOD) or whatever comes to your mind and could work for your project (it depends on far too many things). If there's no way to optimize on any way, #if for low HW and pop/fade in/out a "loading, please wait" screen between scenes (show canvas, load scene, hide canvas). that screen will HANG in there (literally) while the scene is loading

Answer (score 5):

The time it takes to load your level is determined by the things that are referenced in your scene. The only way to cut loading time is to remove things.

You mentioned it would be fine to load some things after the level has started. You can do this using [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html). However, this will only benefit you if there are no references to the thing you are loading. For example, if you have 100 trees in your scene it won't do you any good reducing that to 10. The tree is still referenced and will have to be loaded before your level can start. If you eliminate all of them then your level can start without loading the tree. It is then up to you to load it using Resources.Load and start planting them, maybe over the course of several frames to prevent a hickup.